# How to interpret 尽一份责任？

Tags: meaning

This article is about IBE, Imaging Biodiversity Expedition.

怎样为野生动物保护尽一份责任
Maybe: How to best serve and protect wildlife.

I'm having trouble with understanding:  尽一份责任  Possible answers:
1. give the highest priority to all responsibilities
2. maximise (wildlife protection)
3. fulfill all the duties (of wildlife protection)
4. meet all the demands (of wildlife protection)

I don't understand quite how they mean 尽一份责任 I think it is '尽 all the responsibilities', but then, what is '尽’here? Maybe 尽 is 'all' here? '尽一份’ is maybe 'each and every'?

徐健和他的朋友曾苦苦琢磨，怎样为野生动物保护尽一份责任。他们不分昼夜地奔波，渴望拍出足以使人疯狂的照片，…

然后说：于是徐健成立了社会企业IBE，为保护区、政府等各类课题服务，…

Comment: You can think of 尽 as maximize or exhaust [fulfill like @TangHo said below is good too].  一份 together with 尽 is always singular meaning: one's own. Your sentence has it's "who": 徐健和他的朋友 with 尽一份责任 - They want to live up to their responsibilities.

Comment: enter 尽一份责任 into jukuu：be obliged to/it is one's turn to play,do one's part

Comment: @Ree：jukuu does not have a direct example of '尽一份责任‘ @all:If I rewrite: 徐健琢磨怎样最好地保护野生动物。 do I have  the same meaning as the original?

Comment: @Pedroski you got the gist of it, but it the original stresses more the point of doing ones responsibilities.

Answer (score 3):

> 尽  http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2662/
>
> *[3] [v] try one's best; devote to*

尽 in 尽责任 means 'try one's best to  [fulfill](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fulfill)'

'**尽**一份责任' means '**try** (their) **best to fulfill** (their) share of duty'

More examples of 尽 (v):

**尽**一分努力 (**devote all** effort one can summon )

**尽**人事 (**exhaust** one's ability)

**尽**心**尽**力 (**exhaust** one's wit and strength)

Answer (score 3):

"to pull one's own weight" may be fit 尽一份责任